# CONFIG GET command is not allowed from script

Tags: redis, lua, command

I am working in a scenario with one Redis Master and several replicas, distributed in two cities, for geographic redundancy. My point is, for some reason, in a Lua script I need to know in which city the active instance is running. I thought, quite simple :

redis.call("config", "get", "bind"), and knowing the server IP I will determine the city. Not quite:

```
$ cat config.lua 
redis.call("config", "get", "bind")
$ redis-cli --eval config.lua 
(error) ERR Error running script (call to f_9bfbf1fd7e6331d0e3ec9e46ec28836b1d40ba35): @user_script:1: @user_script: 1: This Redis command is not allowed from scripts
```

Why is "config" not allowed from scripts? First, even though it's no deterministic, there are no write commands.
Second, I am using version 5.0.4, and from version 5 the replication is supposed to be done by effects and not by script propagation.

Any ideas?

Comment: The `CONFIG` command has an "s" flag, which means not allowed from script. It has nothing to do with *deterministic* or *replication*. It seems that this command is disabled from script by design.